# Kivy Cover Whole Screen

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

This is my kivy code:

```
Manager:
StartMenu:
SetupMenu:

<StartMenu>
    name: "start"
    size: root.width, root.height
    GridLayout:
        Image:
            source: "Logo.png"
            keep_ratio: True
            size_hint: 1,1
        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: "center"
            anchor_y: "bottom"
            Button:
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: 242, 242, 242, .50
                width: root.width/5
                text: "Begin"    
                size_hint: None, None
                on_release: 
                    app.root.current: "setUp"
                    root.manager.transition.direction: "left"


</StartMenu>

<SetupMenu>
    name: "setUp"
    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_release: 
            app.root.current: "startMenu"
            root.manager.transition.direction: "left"
```

This is my Python code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
=from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

class StartMenu(Screen):
    pass

class SetupMenu(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class StartMenu(Screen):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("lordofthe90.kv")

class lordOfThe90(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

lordOfThe90.run()
```

How do I make both screens cover the entire window? I force a full screen within my game so I'd require their size to be the same as the screen resolution of the device they're on.
Also, does my code roughly look good? I'm very new to kivy as a whole.

Comment: you could at least put working code with all imports. And then we can copy and run code to see problem. As for me Screen should always cover entire window.

Comment: I had to remove most widgets to run it - and to display it correctly I had to define `rows: 1` in `GridLayout:`

Answer (score 0):

I had to define at least `rows: 1` in `GridLayout:` to display it correctly.